# AS3 Object Coercion

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi guys I get this coercion error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Shape@41754601 to flash.display.
```

When I create an instance of a MovieClip from my library:

```
var childmc:ChipEasy = new ChipEasy();
Canvas.Map.Tiles.addChild(childmc);
```

When I try to access all the children like:

```
for (var i:int=0; i<Canvas.Map.Tiles.numChildren-1; i++)
{
    var mc:MovieClip = Canvas.Map.Tiles.getChildAt(i);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One (or more) of the children is `Shape`, it can't be converted to `MovieClip`. Get children as `DisplayObject`, then you may check

```
if (child is MovieClip)
{
     var mc:MovieClip = child as MovieClip; //safe cast
}
```

Comment: I am such a moron! I had the remains of a shape in my empty placeholder, many thanks.